# Compute the reverse cumulative product from right to left

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code works perfectly:

```
import numpy as np

def transformation(C):
    # Transform  0 and 1 to -1 and +1.
    V = 2. * C - 1

    # Compute the cumulative product from left to right
    V = np.cumprod(V, dtype=np.int8)

    return V

C = np.random.choice(np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.int8), size=(3,))
C = transformation(C)
```

As you can see, `np.cumprod` performs cumulative product from left to right. How can I reverse this to be from right to left instead?

Comment: Why are you not reversing your array ? Doing `V[::-1]` ?

Comment: @IMCoins Didn't see that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse your array such as V = V[::-1]